# Python: how to create dictionary list function that searches specific IPs address

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create list of ip addresses. I want to loop through the dictionary and checks the ip address with if condition. If the address is Swedish I want to add it to a list. Once the dictionary has been checked, I want to loop through the list and print all Swedish IP-addresses. What am I doing wrong?

```
def ipAddresses(listOfIps):   ### list of ip addresses in dictionary
    ipAddresses = {"255.255.255.0 / 21": "Suomi",
    "192.168.64.96 / 27": "Suomi",
    "32.204.65.64 / 27": "Suomi",
    "41.57.128.0 / 22": "Sweden",
    "31.204.70.96 / 27": "Suomi",
    "41.58.10.0 / 16": "Sweden",
    "31.217.192.162 / 21": "Suomi",
    "10.42.100.136 / 29": "Suomi",
    "32.100.148.0 / 24": "Suomi",
    "41.67.128.0 / 18": "Sweden",
   "10.10.10.100 / 24": "Suomi",
    "10.10.100.1 / 24": "Suomi"
    }

    for ip, country in listOfIps.items():  ## if ip address is Swedish, add it to a list
        if (country == Sweden):
            ipAddresses.append(ip,country)
        return ipAddresses


def Osio6():  ## loop through the list and print all swedish IP-addresses
    listOfIps = []
    for ipAddress in listOfIps:
        listOfIps.append(ipAddress)
    
        ipAddressList = Swedish(listOfIps)
        print ("List of Swedish IP-addresses are: \n", ipAddressList, "\n")
```

Comment: Why did you not do it?

Comment: `print("\n".join(ip for ip, country in ipAddresses.values() if country == "Sweden"))`

Comment: `mylist = [ipaddress for ipaddress, location in mydictionary.items() if location == "Sweden"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can store Swedish addresses to a list and then print the list (you can do it with help of list comprehension also):

```
ipAddresses = {
    "1.172.152.0 / 21": "Finland",
    "31.204.64.96 / 27": "Finland",
    "31.204.65.64 / 27": "Finland",
    "41.57.120.0 / 22": "Sweden",
    "31.204.66.96 / 27": "Finland",
    "41.58.0.0 / 16": "Sweden",
    "31.217.192.0 / 21": "Finland",
    "32.42.29.136 / 29": "Finland",
    "32.106.148.0 / 24": "Finland",
    "41.67.128.0 / 18": "Sweden",
    "32.106.181.0 / 24": "Finland",
    "32.106.182.0 / 24": "Finland"
}

# store swedish addresses to list:
swedish_addresses = []
for ip, country in ipAddresses.items():
    if country == 'Sweden':
        swedish_addresses.append(ip)

# print swedish addresses:
for address in swedish_addresses:
    print(address)
```

Prints:

```
41.57.120.0 / 22
41.58.0.0 / 16
41.67.128.0 / 18
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
ipAddresses = {
"1.172.152.0 / 21": "Finland",
"31.204.64.96 / 27": "Finland",
"31.204.65.64 / 27": "Finland",
"41.57.120.0 / 22": "Sweden",
"31.204.66.96 / 27": "Finland",
"41.58.0.0 / 16": "Sweden",
"31.217.192.0 / 21": "Finland",
"32.42.29.136 / 29": "Finland",
"32.106.148.0 / 24": "Finland",
"41.67.128.0 / 18": "Sweden",
"32.106.181.0 / 24": "Finland",
"32.106.182.0 / 24": "Finland"
}

print('-'*80 + "\nSwedish IP Addresses\n" + '-'*80)
[print(key) for key in ipAddresses.keys() if ipAddresses[key] == "Sweden"]
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Swedish IP Addresses
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
41.57.120.0 / 22
41.58.0.0 / 16
41.67.128.0 / 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
ipAddresses = {
"1.172.152.0 / 21": "Finland",
"31.204.64.96 / 27": "Finland",
"31.204.65.64 / 27": "Finland",
"41.57.120.0 / 22": "Sweden",
"31.204.66.96 / 27": "Finland",
"41.58.0.0 / 16": "Sweden",
"31.217.192.0 / 21": "Finland",
"32.42.29.136 / 29": "Finland",
"32.106.148.0 / 24": "Finland",
"41.67.128.0 / 18": "Sweden",
"32.106.181.0 / 24": "Finland",
"32.106.182.0 / 24": "Finland"
}
new = dict((k,v) for k, v in ipAddresses.items() if v =='Sweden' )
print(new)
```

Output

```
{'41.57.120.0 / 22': 'Sweden', '41.58.0.0 / 16': 'Sweden', '41.67.128.0 / 18': 'Sweden'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ipAddresses = {
"1.172.152.0 / 21": "Finland",
"31.204.64.96 / 27": "Finland",
"31.204.65.64 / 27": "Finland",
"41.57.120.0 / 22": "Sweden",
"31.204.66.96 / 27": "Finland",
"41.58.0.0 / 16": "Sweden",
"31.217.192.0 / 21": "Finland",
"32.42.29.136 / 29": "Finland",
"32.106.148.0 / 24": "Finland",
"41.67.128.0 / 18": "Sweden",
"32.106.181.0 / 24": "Finland",
"32.106.182.0 / 24": "Finland"
}

countryToSearchFor="Sweden"
swedenIps=[]
for ip, country in ipAddresses.items():
  if country==countryToSearchFor:
      swedenIps.append(ip)
  
for swedenIp in swedenIps:
    print(swedenIp)
```